# Do I really need this circuit vent if the sink vertical drain segment is 4' away from the vertical dry vent?

Tags: plumbing

Here is the layout and I am questioning the need to have the purple segment
the green blue selected segment is already in place, the green segment between the shower vent and the sink is what I am building (still dry fitting the pieces but I did not drill the holes for the studs to the left of the vertical green segment
As mentioned the distance between the two green verticals is 4'

I am also considering an air admittance valve
[image]

Update: Here is why I need to go down and not horizontal with the drain
[image]

Comment: Why are you not taking a vent vertically out and up of the top of the sanitary tee up and then turn 90 to go horizontal to the vent?

Comment: those studs are supporting cabintes on the other side and a hood range. They will also support a floating vaniti cabinet and a mirror on this side so I would drill them as little as I can (only drilling itself is discouraging enough :-)) )

Comment: But you are drilling holes for the drain pipe? I don't think holes in the studs for  1 1/2" vent pipe are going to render the wall incapable of supporting cabinets and a vanity. I have seen kitchen walls  with cabinets  that have  horizontal vents in them.

Comment: Don't have that much experience I prefer not to risk (in this case I will have to sets of holes if I do what you are suggesting)

Comment: One set of holes for drain and one set of holes for vent is standard operating procedure. Make sure you put a drill prevention plate on the stud where the pipe passes through the stud  so you do not drill into the drain or vent pipes.

Answer (score 1):

If the slope of the drain is 1/4"-per-foot you can do without the pink vent.  Be sure to measure your slope with a level.  Don't just measure from the floor.

You don't need an AAV to delete the pink vent.

```
trap arm size    trap max developed length @ 1/4"-per-foot slope
1 1/4"           5 feet
1 1/2"           6 feet
2"               8 feet
```

Instead of the green branch drain having a vertical drop, just run it horizontally (with a 1/4"-per-foot slope) over to the corner.  That is within the max length before siphoning could occur.
[image: edited CAD drawing with red line for branch drain]

Comment: worse come to worse I could install the AAV later correct ?
When I drill the holes I draw a horizontal on the studs from where I want the lowest point to be. Then at the other end I calculate (distance times 0.25") and  I draw a line at that point. After that I connect the two above with a line on the studs and I drill on each stud where the now diagonal line is (middle of it) That will guarantee me that the holes are perfectly aligned. I do not use the ground as reference as that is misleading

Comment: Sure, there's even a product called **Magic Trap** which is a kit containing a sink trap and a small vent all together.  It's easy to add later if you need to.  You shouldn't have to based on your plan, though.

Comment: Hmm it seems that your answer is wrong at this is breaking the rule of the weir trap arm
https://www.buellinspections.com/weir-d-science-p-trap-works/
The trap weir must be able to "see" the vent take off. So neither of the solutions work, I would need to go horizontal straight from the point where the trap arm enters the wall
 Am I misunderstanding this ?

Comment: If your slope is correct, your trap weir will be beneath the vent tee.  That's the reason the *developed length of trap arm* is based on the diameter of the drain and its slope.  The link you posted is trying to explain this.  **Do not install a flat horizontal branch,** it will clog.  1/4"-per-foot is the correct installation.

Comment: yes but the point is that in the trap arm the water could fill in the entire section of the pipe and on its way down on that vertical it will create a suction effect and it will take the water in the p trap with it

Comment: Right, and if the slope of your branch is correct, that problem can't happen.  That's why there is guidance on the developed length of the branch.  If you install it as discussed, you won't have a siphon problem.

Comment: the picture with the S trap clearly shows that as a problem

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what your concern is.  I didn't notice the trap is so high up within the sink.  Raise the branch drain and vent tee to the same level as where the sink connects into the wall.

Comment: I think that the trap arm must stat horizontal but the whole thing is ruined by the fact that the pipe heads down vertically which practically allows the suction effect? Do you have an example of a design like mine somewhere is a book or a reference?

Comment: This article has some good diagrams.  The one titled **maximum allowable trap arm length** is similar to what you can do.  Just don't install your branch as *flat,* it does need to have the 1/4"-per-foot slope.  But remove the vertical drop by the sink.  https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o

Comment: no I can't do that due restictions imposed by the cabinet and the position of the P trap relative to the studs. It is almost aligned with the stud to the left so going vertical is the only way there. A 90 in the studs perpedicular to the wall will get the arm on a direction parallel with the P trap and I can' change the direction there

Comment: yes but that is all horizontal, not my case

Comment: You can't route the drain like the red line I drew in the edited drawing, above?

Comment: see the update in the initial post I added a picture there

Comment: @JeffWheeler you’re not actually saying to route the drain as in the red line in your diagram, but rather that the red line would be a vent? I find the diagram confusing. The P trap has to be there, and the vent has to be downstream of the P trap. One issue is admitting air to allow water to drain without signing the trap dry. Another issue is that the sewer gases are pressurized and will bubble up through the water in the trap from the downstream side if they can’t escape through a vent.

Comment: The red line should be the trap arm.  That separates into drain and vent at the vent tee.  MiniMe says there's some reason he can't put it at that elevation but I looked at his drawing and didn't understand the reason.  He can use an AAV to work around that if he needs.  He could also lower the trap (by extending the riser to the sink) if that helps.